Elementary proofs of the v1-periodicity of the Hopf map
I've been learning the periodicity theorem recently, and I know that the Hopf map $\eta \in \pi_1(\mathbb S)$ is $v_1$-periodic, which can be shown by machinery like ANSS. On the other hand, chromatic level 1 essentially consists of stuffs which are related to $K$-theory. So my question is:

Are there any $K$-theory-approaches to the fact that $\eta \in \pi_1(\mathbb S)$ is $v_1$-periodic?

Any help would be appreciated.
